# How to boot into existing Ubuntu drive on a new computer?

Tags: ubuntu, boot, grub, macintosh

I had an old IBM Thinkpad laptop with Ubuntu installed die on me, but the hard drive is still intact. I want to move the installation onto an old Macbook Air I have lying around  but I'm having trouble booting it on the Mac. I can get to the grub bootloader screen fine, but when I select Ubuntu it just shows a blank purple-ish almost black screen, forever.

I'm suspecting this is because of the hardware differences and I have incorrect drivers or maybe I need to mess with /etc/fstab. Does this sound correct or could there be other issues preventing me from booting the existing hard drive on a new machine?

I really don't want to have to reinstall my Ubuntu and re-configure everything, so I need a better way than booting from the old hard drive directl. I was also planning on cloning the old drive onto the SSD on the Mac after I get it booting, with Clonezilla.

TL;DR: How to boot existing Ubuntu drive on a new machine?

Comment: While it _might_ be possible to boot the old drive/OS on a new system, there are so many technical considerations, compatibility issues, and workarounds to problems you would probably need to put in place that the easiest way forward is probably to install a fresh copy of Ubuntu. You can certainly try. But it is by no means the easiest or most efficient method, and you probably won't find many people interested in the topic that have experience or input that will help.

Comment: Since you said you can get to the GRUB screen, it sounds like the kernel is attempting to use the wrong kind of display driver and hanging as a result. It might be trying to use a VGA-compatible text mode, which a Macbook won't necessarily have, or it might be trying to use a SVGA framebuffer mode that is not supported by your Macbook Air model. I'd first make a fresh dummy installation of Ubuntu on the Macbook, verify that the display works, then package up a copy of its `/etc` directory tree, move the package to the old system and run `diff` to see the differences between the installations.

Comment: Ok I might try running the diff on the two, the only problem is that the MacBook air is the only machine I have access to, as the old machine is dead. So I can't make a proper backup of the old Ubuntu install, I only have the original hard drive to work with. I'm wondering if there is a software that can help me migrate to a new install on a Mac, given these constraints?